# How can we knock out a proton specially to change one element to another?

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering, protons, elements

I know one can simply excite a nucleon from a  nucleus by radiating gamma rays on that nucleus, or knock the nucleus with neutrons or protons.

But how can we knock out a proton specially to change one element to the another? Are there any special methods for such process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking specifically about making a proton in a nucleus go away, one way to do it is by smacking an electron into a proton, which changes it into a neutron and a neutrino. In this manner the proton "goes away", but not by being knocked loose.

Neutrons can be knocked loose from some nuclei by striking them with high-energy protons, a process called *spallation*.

Comment: The classic would be the 14N(n,p)14C reaction in the atmosphere.

Comment: yep yep! thanks for the comment. -NN